# Using EJB local as well as remote

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I have a service (interface `ParameterService`) with an EJB (`@Stateless` and `@Remote`) implementation (`ParameterServiceImpl`). As for what it does: it resolves parameters using `ParameterProvider` implementations, which are discovered at runtime (CDI lookup in `BeanManager`).

This EJB is deployed in two EARs:

- in the **first EAR**, the **EJB is used local only**. The EAR ships with a `ParameterProvider` implementation which reads/writes parameters using the database.
- in the **second EAR**, the **EJB is used local** (can resolve local parameters using the available `ParameterProvider`s, which read from property files or system properties). It is **also used remotely**, within a `RemoteParameterProvider`, which delegates parameter reads/writes to the remote EJB in the first EAR.

I'm struggling with the second EAR, as it does not resolve the remote EJB.
When I inject (for testing) the EJBs as follows:

```
@EJB
private ParameterService localParameterService;

@EJB(lookup = "java:global/commons/parameter-service/ParameterService")
private ParameterService remoteParameterService;
```

... the `localParameterService` is available:

> Proxy for remote EJB StatelessEJBLocator{appName='mobile', 
>   moduleName='mobile-admin-war', distinctName='', 
>   beanName='ParameterServiceImpl', view='interface [...].ParameterService'}

whereas the `remoteParameterService` is `null`. No exceptions are thrown or logged, and I checkted the JNDI name, it is correct.

Is there something wrong with my approach (using EJB locally as well as remote), or am I missing something?

**EDIT**: *Interface and class annotations:*

```
public interface ParameterService { ... }

@Stateless
@Remote(ParameterService .class)
public class ParameterServiceImpl implements ParameterService { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the injection is confused.
How your ParameterService implementation and interfaces look like?
And what server do you use?

Comment: The implementation and interface are bare simple, I added them to the question. The implementation has no fields, just simple methods). As for the server, it's Wildfly 8.

Answer (score 0):

you most deployed both in separate way or they will share the same JVM instance and ParameterServiceImpl will be local forever and ever.

Comment: I explicitely want it to be local, but the point is: I want it to be remote as well. I used this pattern (use local service, which may delegate to a remote instance) successfully with other technologies, but it somehow doesn't seem to work with Java EE out of the box...